# MSSQL via JDBC Error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, exception, jdbc

I am trying to access a MSSQL database via Java and just wrote a small testing class to see if the connection works at all. I've added the JDBC driver to the buildpath via a maven dependency.

TRANSLATION for exception:
is not supported by this driver. Use the class library offers 'sqljdbc4.jar', support for JDBC 4.0

However, when executing the code a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException is thrown. Below is the complete errorlog:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Die Java-Laufzeitumgebung (Java Runtime Environment, JRE), Version 1.7, wird von diesem Treiber nicht unterstützt. Verwenden Sie die     Klassenbibliothek 'sqljdbc4.jar', die Unterstützung für JDBC 4.0 bietet.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.<init>(SQLServerConnection.java:304)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1011)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
at test.TestJDBC.dbTest.main(dbTest.java:28)
```

Here's my testing class:

```
package test.TestJDBC;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class dbTest {

@SuppressWarnings( "nls" )
public static void main( final String args[] ) {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {

        // the sql server driver string
        Class.forName( "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" );

        // the sql server url
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://[dbserver]:1433;DatabaseName=[dbname]";

        // get the sql server database connection
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url, "XXX", "YYY" );

        System.out.println( "Connected." );

        // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.
        String SQL = "SELECT X, Y, Z FROM ABC";
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( SQL );

        // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            System.out.println( rs.getString( 1 ) + " " + rs.getString( 2 ) );
        }

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.out.println( "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten:" );
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit( 0 );
    }
}

}
```

I would appreciate if someone could point me to the error I've made, as I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: "I've added the JDBC driver to the buildpath via a maven dependency." ... and which dependency would that be? Hint: it's telling you you're using the wrong version of the library.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am using a third party repository integrated into maven (...\com\microsoft\sqlserver\sqljdbc4\4.0). It points to the sqljdbc4.jar file. When opening it in Eclipse I can also see the correct packages com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc and microsoft.sql in there. The first one is exactly the package I refer to in the Class.forName declaration, so I don't see what's faulty here :(

Comment: try executing `mvn dependency:tree` on your project. It looks like the wrong sqljdbc.jar is landing on the classpath. Maybe it is included as a transient dependency from somewhere else? If it is then you can define an `exclude`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Translate says that the Exception is:

> The Java Runtime Environment (Java Runtime Environment, JRE), version 1.7, is not supported by this driver. Use the Class Library 'sqljdbc4.jar' which provides support for JDBC 4.0.

so it looks like you need to download the latest version of the JDBC driver via the page here

[Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to translate it for you guys... I am using the exact same .jar-file as the message suggests. That's why I don't really understand the message at all. I also tried using Java 1.6 to execute. Same error message (just saying "version 1.6" in that case).